# ReactJS: Pattern for JSX attribute names

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I have the following JSX sample, which is a SVG element:

```
<svg className={className} viewBox="0 0 48 48" version="1.1"
  onClick={this.props.onClick} aria-label="Some random label">
  <g fill="none">
    <line strokeWidth="2" x1="24" y1="14" x2="24" y2="34"/>
    <line strokeWidth="2" x1="14" y1="24" x2="34" y2="24"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

In raw HTML `strokeWidth` is represented as `stroke-width`. It seems to me that all JSX attributes follow the camel-case format. So, I immediately thought on adding `ariaLabel` instead of `aria-label`.

**Question**: Is there a pattern for JSX attributes? If yes, why `aria-*` does not follow this pattern?

In fact, I like the idea of having `stroke-*` so that I don't have to preprocess my raw svg to reactjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PR request has been merged in React to pass all the SVG attributes along. Thanks to Dan Abramov for working on this. It will be available in the next React release.

The camel-case style is now deprecated but still supported behind a warning.

See more in [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5617#issuecomment-167259192)

Answer (score 1):

The aria attributes are standard html attributes that React has decided to keep formatted as is. They do specify that any custom html attributes you make should be prefixed with `data-*` and on this page seem to suggest using the `attribute-*` syntax only for these special cases https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html

The standard format is camel case https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-differences.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. but the part I still dont understand is why stroke-* attributes do not follow the same convention.

Comment: Looks like they the aria and custom html stuff are the exception rather than the rule. I'll update my answer to point this out. The standard react stuff is camel cased: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-differences.html